# Animation theory (natural animations)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation, random

I want, for example: to animate how a bird is flying through the sky, i am not talking about the animation of the wings, but how to animate an object random over a canvas.

I use to animate those kind of objects with a lot of randomisation, for example: move [object] from a to b (random distance, random speed, random x, random y, etc.).

But is that really the best way to do it? or is there any algorithm theory available on how to achieve the most natural behaviour.

The animation can be a bird, but it could also be dust, or flying sand)

(I hope my question is clear enough)

Comment: To have a realistic animation in such a case you would require a library with a physics engine to calculate such things, but this is nothing for javascript as it requires too much resources to calculate

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but saying that javascript isnt powerfull enough is absolutely not true. I want to learn the theory behind it.

Comment: Sorry, this is my opinion :) Javascript is not capable to calculate realistic physics during runtime as it is a script language.. but there are some libs out there (Like: http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/ ) maybe just take look at it

Answer (score 4):

In fact, a bird is rarely on its own in the sky, maybe you could have a look at [flocking behavior of boids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids).

They basically lie on 3 rules known as

> - separation: steer to avoid crowding local flockmates alignment:
> - steer towards the average heading of local flockmates cohesion:
> - steer to move toward the average position (center of mass) of local
>     flockmate

This said you can imagine it is a bit different from sand and dust movement calculation, because these are actual physics problem (mostly [fluid mechanics navier stokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_mechanics#Navier.E2.80.93Stokes_equations))

But I'm pretty sure if you don't actually want to be accurate (navier stokes aren't accurate) you could hack some of boids rules to move particles.

Comment: Thanks! your answer will help me in achieving my animation.

Answer (score 3):

Answer extracted from this [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23868/algorithm-for-random-flight-of-a-fly)

> [Lévy flights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight) or [brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) should work. These are random walks
>   where at each time step the insect moves a random direction and
>   distance. They differ in what distribution the random variables are
>   sampled from.
>
> The motion of hunting sharks can be modeled as brownian motion when
>   prey is plentiful and lévy flight when prey is scarce.
>
> Depending on what you use it for, you might want to restrict their
>   motion (to keep them near a specific part of a level) or limit the
>   acceleration (to make them appear to have have more inertia).

Comment: Thanks! also your answer will help me in achieving my animation. I think I was looking for the brownian motion.

Comment: @barry You're welcome, good luck with the brownian motion, sounds like a really interesting topic!